# pstricks and pdf option

Tags: pstricks, auto-pst-pdf

I've noticed a problem with the latest version of `pstricks`: I used to compile files containing pstricks code with `pdflatex`, using the `pdf` option of the document class. Now it doesn't work,, and produces an error:

```
                                              %
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...\expandafter \c@lor@to@ps #1#2\@@
                                                  \else \expandafter \expand...
l.15 ...lor =IndianRed ]{0}{TwoPi}{0.5 + 2*cos(x)}
                                                  %
[1 Non-PDF special ignored! Non-PDF special ignored! Non-PDF special
ignored! Non-PDF special ignored! Non-PDF special ignored! Non-PDF
special ignored! Non-PDF special ignored! Non-PDF special ignored!
```

exactly as though `auto-pst-pdf` were not loaded. Loading auto-pst-pdf explicitly in the preamble, at the right place, solves the problem, but this means all files with pstricks code will have to be modified.

Does anyone know where this problem comes from, and if there is a solution?

*Minimal working example:*

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, pdf, svgnames]{standalone}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage{ pst-plot}
% \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=2.5cm, arrowinset=0.15, ticksize=2.5pt -2.5pt, labelFontSize=\footnotesize, tickwidth =0.6pt}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-1.9)(3.9,1.9)
    \psaxes[arrows=->, linecolor=LightSteelBlue, tickcolor=LightSteelBlue] (0,0)(-1.6,-1.9)(3.6,1.9)[$x$,-110][$y$,-140]
    \psset{linewidth=1.2pt, plotpoints=200, plotstyle=curve, polarplot, algebraic, labelsep=0.5em}
    \psplot[linecolor =IndianRed ]{0}{TwoPi}{0.5 + 2*cos(x)}%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With [pstricks.sty](https://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/pstricks.sty) and [pstricks.tex](https://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/pstricks.tex) this will work with

```
pdflatex --shell-escape exa.tex
```

Edit: It will change in the next few days: instead of using the option `pdf`,
you should load package `pstricks-pdf`. I'll upload it before weekend.

The example code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, pdf, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=2.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-2)(3,2)
\psset{linewidth=2pt, plotpoints=200, plotstyle=curve, polarplot, algebraic, labelsep=0.5em}
\psaxes[arrows=->,linewidth=0.5pt,labels=none,gridstyle=](0,0)(-1,-2)(3,2)[$x$,-110][$y$,-140]
\psplot[linecolor=blue]{0}{TwoPi}{0.5 + 2*cos(x)}%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]